# App.xaml point to a library in a sub-folder

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, app.xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using the [material design XAML toolkit](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) library, currently in the app.xaml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Application . . .>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

However, I used [pretty-bin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PrettyBin) to move the library into a /lib sub-folder, as such it can no longer find the resource directory. I'm struggling to work out the correct syntax how would I reference these files from the sub-folder. Thank you.

**EDIT**

[image]

**CODE**

```
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;/component/lib/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/lib/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/lib/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/lib/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/lib/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Flipper.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/lib/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.Indigo.Named.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**EDIT 2**

[image]

Comment: These are called pack URIs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf

Comment: Pretty sure all you need to do is make the last part like `/component/LIB/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml` right?

Comment: That hasn't appeared to have worked, is there any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I capitalized LIB to emphasize it, you made sure the paths match right? Do the assembly names match? Try rebuilding after a change too.

Comment: I've attached some screen shoots above, as I still can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Can I see a screen shot of your MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml in your solution explorer? That file should be in a Themes folder within a lib folder in a MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf assembly

Comment: Also remove the stray / in front of component, my bad.

Comment: I removed the stray "/" and it still didn't appear to like it, I've not actually got a folder, the pretty-bin tool appeared to add the above code in the csprojg file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find an answer, I needed to edit the App.config file and place inside:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
```

I followed this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element)